# How to get return statement in python recursion

Tags: python, recursion

```
def rec(i):
    try:
        print(i)
        if i==1:
            print('from if i ==1')
            return i
        rec(i-1)
    except:
        print('un hadled exception')
        return 100
    return 99        
        
print(rec(3))
```

im getting following answers

```
3
2
1
from if i ==1
99
```

How can I stop iteration at 1 and return 1 instead of 99

Comment: `return rec(i-1)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to recursively count down from some number and return 1 when it reaches the end.

```
def rec(i):
    print(i)
    if i == 1:
        return i
    rec(i-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the code is on line 7 you shouldnt call function again. If you use return instead of recall the function, you can get output that you want.

```
def rec(i):
    try:
        print(i)
        if i==1:
            print('from if i ==1')
            return i
        return rec(i-1)
    except:
        print('un hadled exception')
        return 100
    return 99        
        
print(rec(3))
```

The output is

```
3
2
1
from if i ==1
1
```